# Etymology of "Houston, we have a problem!"

Tags: etymology, phrases

Where did the phrase "Houston, we have a problem" come from? I have heard it used a lot in movies. In which situations would it be used correctly?

Comment: A misquotation of Apollo 13. [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/houston-we-have-a-problem.html)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. I was wondering too about 'beam me up scotty'.

Comment: "Beam me up Scotty" is from Star Trek, although it's another misquotation. Have you tried simply googling these phrases for their origins?

Answer (score 3):

The origin of the phrase is from the 1970 Apollo 13 moon mission, and was used by the astronauts to report in a remarkably calm and understated way what turned out to be the first indication of a major catastrophe that almost killed all on board and required a major rescue effort. 'Houston' was the callsign of mission control (based in Houston, Texas). The phrase is a slight misquote, and was actually said as "Houston, we've had a problem". The web provides plenty of transcripts of the full conversation.

The phrase was picked up for general usage, especially after the [1995 Apollo 13 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (which used the phrase as a tagline). It tends to be used humorously for minor situations (since people in life-threatening situations don't tend to make jokes).

Comment: *what seemed at the time like a relatively minor fault* I don't this is quite right. There was a loud bang, the spacecraft shook, and they lost voltage on a power bus. This all happened before Swigert and Lovell said the famous phrase, so I don't think they thought it was a minor fault. They were keeping their cool, and that's really the point of the phrase to me -- it's a famous understatement.

Comment: After another look at the transcripts I agree with you, Ben.